# Get distinct values from each field within mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

How to get the distinct values of all the fields within the mongodb collection using single query.

```
{ "_id": "1", "Gender": "male", "car": "bmw" , "house":"2bhk" , "married_to": "kalpu"},
{ "_id": "2", "Gender": "female", "car": nan , "house":"3bhk", "married_to": "kalpu"},
{ "_id": "3", "Gender": "female", "car": "audi", "house":"1bhk", "married_to": "deepa"},
```

This is an example with few fields, In my actual collection, each document has atleast 50 fields. So how to query effeciently that will return unique values within each of the fields? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer expected:

for each field,

```
  Gender:"male", "female"
  car   :"bmw", "audi",.....
  house : "3hbk","2bhk","1bhk"
  married_to: "kalpu","deepa",....
  ....
  ....
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline `$group stage` with `$addToSet operator`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      Gender: {
        "$addToSet": "$Gender"
      },
      car: {
        "$addToSet": "$car"
      },
      house: {
        "$addToSet": "$house"
      },
      married_to: {
        "$addToSet": "$married_to"
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Working Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S0iu-g_WFsD)

Comment: hey, did this answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks, Yes it worked, But how to avoid "null" values being considered as distinct values.

Comment: null values are considered the same