# MongoDB query: keys and their distinct values (each key independently)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If you have this collection of objects:

```json
{ "a": 10, "b": 20, "c": 30 }
{ "a": 11, "b": 20, "c": 31 }
{ "a": 10, "b": 20, "c": 31 }
```

1. There is a way to [get distinct values](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), for example, for field "a":

   ```json
   [10, 11]
   ```
2. There is also a way to [get distinct values of any tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973725/how-to-efficiently-perform-distinct-with-multiple-keys), for example, for pairs of ("b", "c"):

   ```json
   [
       {"b": 20, "c": 30},
       {"b": 20, "c": 31}
   ]
   ```

**Is there a way to query distinct values for each field individually in a single query?**

For example, I can simply use query 1 above 3 times for "a", "b", "c":

```json
[10, 11]
[20]
[30, 31]
```

But I guess it might be less efficient and there should be a better option.

**Bonus:** How to do it if the list of fields is **not known** upfront?

Ideally, the single query should return all keys and their distinct values:

```json
{
    "a": [10, 11],
    "b": [20],
    "c": [30, 31]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get distinct values from each field within mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592489/get-distinct-values-from-each-field-within-mongodb-collection)

Comment: It does, but I find answer of @ray below even more generic (where list of fields may not be known upfront).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't know the full list of the fields beforehand, you need to use `$objectToArray` to convert the `$$ROOT` document into an array of k-v tuples. Then group by the field name and `$addToSet` the values.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      arr: {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$arr"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "arr.k": {
        $ne: "_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$arr.k",
      values: {
        "$addToSet": "$arr.v"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tJh2efciPYJ)